# ConfigurationFile path for web.config is being loaded from the wrong project

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

Warning: I am an IIS/ASP/Razor newb. I am using VS2013.

I have a solution with 2 web projects, let's call then `Main` and `Methods`. `Main` is a Razor MVC project, and `Methods` is just a generic web project. `Methods` references `Main`. I am attempting to add and use connection strings to the `web.config` file for `Methods`.

However, when I attempt to access the strings in a function, they are not available. I have discovered that this is probably because the `web.config` file that is being loaded is the one for the `Main` project, instead of `Methods` (according to `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.ConfigurationFile`).

Why might this be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because Main is the program that runs - so its the web.config that gets loaded. I suspect you may have the projects setup slightly wrong...

Do you need two web projects? Would Methods ever be run independently from Main - if not make Methods a [Class Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f3cye135%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), keep all your config in the web.config of Main. You will be able to reference all the config from either project (as Methods would be hosted in Main)